# VPN Gateway peering

Tags: azure, vpn, azure-virtual-network, openvpn, azure-vpn

I know Virtual network peering is a thing but just like that is VPN Gateway peering is a thing? if so then if a VPN Gateway(**A**) with *AD AuthN*(OpenVPN SSL tunnel type) and a VPN Gateway(**B**) with *Azure certificate-based authN* with SSTP(SSL) tunnel type, Can A and B be peered.

Questions based on above:

1. Do we have to do S2S peering setup between A and B with manual routing for each to access any resource from A to B and vice versa?
2. What is the limitation of this setup and advantages(if any)?
3. Will it be called a Hybrid solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have two VPN gateways in Azure, you could configure the VNet-to-VNet connections to connect Azure VNets to each other. You don't need manual routing. VNet-to-VNet supports connecting virtual networks. Connecting multiple Azure virtual networks together doesn't require a VPN device unless cross-premises connectivity is required.

> When you connect a virtual network to another virtual network with a
> VNet-to-VNet connection type (VNet2VNet), it's similar to creating a
> Site-to-Site IPsec connection to an on-premises location. Both
> connection types use a VPN gateway to provide a secure tunnel with
> IPsec/IKE and function the same way when communicating. However, they
> differ in the way the local network gateway is configured.
>
> When you create a VNet-to-VNet connection, the local network gateway
> address space is automatically created and populated. **If you update
> the address space for one VNet, the other VNet automatically routes to
> the updated address space**. It's typically faster and easier to create
> a VNet-to-VNet connection than a Site-to-Site connection.

You could read [the document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-howto-vnet-vnet-resource-manager-portal#vnet-to-vnet) for more details.

Comment: This means on VNets can be peered not VPN Gateways and in a peered VNet we can have one VPN Gateway as transit.